# Change ng-readonly dynamically

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set the readonly directive value of table cells :-

```
    var node = e.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode;
    var cells = angular.element(node.querySelectorAll("input"));
    //alert(cells.length);
    //$scope.cell_readonly = false;
    cells.attr("ng-readonly" , "false");
```

But I guess this isn't the correct way. Can anyone point out a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

this is how you use it

use it on your ng-repeat to apply to multiple elements

Check the documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly

```
<input type="text" ng-readonly="ctrlBooleanValue" value="I'm read only"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use AngularJs native data one-way binding (*from controller to view*) to control ng-readonly attribute of the element.

Example:

In view,

```
<input type="text" ng-readonly="isReadOnly"/>
```

In controller,

```
 $scope.isReadOnly = true;
```

You can switch state of 'isReadOnly' flag at any point of time from controller.